# Inverting Op-Amp Circuit Problem

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying solve the question shown in the picture below

[image]

(I am assuming the switch is down in the picture, I can't tell)

The equation that I am using is $$\frac{V_{\text{out}}}{V_{\text{in}}} = - \frac{R_{\text{f}}}{R_{\text{in}}}$$ because there is negative feedback.

For 2a), I ignored \$R_4\$ because there is no current input to the op amp, so I am assuming \$R_4\$ can be neglected. I combined \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$ so that the total resistance for \$R_{\text{f}}\$ is \$1000\Omega\$. I then substituted \$V_{\text{in}} = 20\text{ mV}\$, \$R_{\text{in}} =1\text{ }\Omega\$ and rearranged to get \$V_{\text{out}} = -20\text{ V}\$. I am unsure if I applied the right logic to this question and I am don't know how to solve 2b).

This circuit is different from other inverting op amp circuits I have seen which is why I am struggling to answer it. How do I approach a question like this?

Comment: AFAIK your logic seems right in lower position,  for switch in Upper position,  that formula doesn't apply and you have to derive new one. Use ideal op-amp's equivalent circuit for that..

Comment: Simply treat the opamp circuit and the resistive divider separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redraw the circuit like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdifkl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The questions you have are essentially the same as finding the voltage at point `a` and `b`.

You worked question `a` correctly.

Now you can easily find out the current through R3 and use Ohm's law to find the drop across it. From the known voltage at `a` and the drop across R3, you can find the voltage at `b`.

Alternately, you know the voltage at the op-amp inverting input, and you can use the voltage drop across R2 to find V(`b`).

Comment: Thanks very much for your informative answer, I really appreciate the diagram too. I have done what you said and calculated the voltage to be 8V at b, is this correct?

Comment: @s.twenty you are wrong. It is not 8V. It is -8V.

Comment: @Chupacabras Thank you for the correction, I forgot the sign must be inverted too

Answer (score 1):

Or much simpler

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkdL9e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Any output resistance inside the feedback loop will be hidden away by *"infinite open loop gain"* a.k.a. ideal operational

You can revert to studying the well known inverting amplifier on the right side of the diagram